# Get all WordPress sidebars

Tags: php, wordpress, global-variables

I'm trying to get a list with all registered sidebars using $wp_registered_sidebars but the global variable returns an empty array.

```
function get_sidebars() {

    global $wp_registered_sidebars;

    $sidebar_options = array();

    foreach ($wp_registered_sidebars as $sidebar)
    {
        $sidebar_options[$sidebar['id']] = $sidebar['name'];
    }

    return $sidebar_options;

}


$fields['sidebar_settings'] = array(
    'active' => array(
        ...
        'values' => get_sidebars(),
        ...
    ),
);
```

Why is the global variable empty and is there another way to store all registered sidebars in an array?

Comment: when are you calling it?

Comment: In addition to @DanielA.White, try to `var_dump($wp_registered_sidebars)`

Comment: You may see [this link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/list-all-sidebar-names)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/list-all-sidebar-names

you get all the sidebar name lists

Answer (score 0):

Heres some functions that you could be looking for:

[dynamic_sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

[wp_get_sidebars_widgets](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_sidebars_widgets)

See this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Sidebars . There's also some good information.